# Return WHERE IN clause rows even if table doesn't contain the given row

Tags: mysql, sql

`mytable` contains records for `id` 1, 2, 3, 10, 12 and 20, and specifically does not include records for `id` 5 and 15.

How can I perform some query such as:

```
SELECT id, id IN (1,5,10,15,20) AS status
FROM mytable
WHERE id IN (1,5,10,15,20);
```

and return records:

```
id  status
1   true
5   false
10  true
15  false
20  true
```

If there was some other table, I could just outer join mytable, but there is none.  The following will certainly not work, but is there some sort of fictional table I can join against?

```
SELECT id, isnull(mytable.id) AS status
FROM *
LEFT OUTER JOIN mytable
WHERE id IN (1,5,10,15,20);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a *derived table* in the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT i.id, (t.id is not null) AS status
FROM (SELECT 1 as id UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 15 UNION ALL SELECT 20
     ) i LEFT JOIN
     mytable t
     ON i.id = t.id;
```

Comment: Ah, I have never used a derived table such as this one, but only dynamically generate the `IN` list.  Potentially going to be big and ugly (could have hundreds of thousands of rows).  Concerns?  Maybe best to leave it to the application?

Comment: @user1032531 better to leave it to the application

Comment: @M0rtiis  Will do.  Thanks